# how to make correctly has many associations in Golang with go

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

let say one teacher has many students and student only has one teacher, how to implement it on Gorm Golang ?

my opinion is

```
type Teacher struct {
   gorm.Model 
   Name string
   Student []Student
}

type Student struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
}
```

is those correct ?? and if not how to make it to be associated? and how about if we query it to create ? should I create another StudentID on it ?

Comment: You cannot put Teacher under Student. the above one looks good. It is not contradicting the design.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Teacher struct {
   gorm.Model 
   Name string
}

type Student struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  TeacherId uint `gorm:"TYPE:integer REFERENCES teachers;index"`
}
```

Comment: let say i have JSON request like this : { studentName: "me", teacher: ["myTeacher", "secondeTeacher"]}, will it created teacherID on student ? ,

Comment: GORM doesn't create records based on ANY json. It is your task to unmarshal JSON to the struct and (may be) map them to the database level models

Comment: I was get confused how to make request for your schema in go, I do like the request like this &req{ teacher: "yess" , student: []student{"tes", "testone"}} then it gonna create the students on teacher

Comment: GORM doesn't work with JSON, to create records you need to use `db.Create()` method https://gorm.io/docs/create.html

Comment: And yes, you need to create Teacher first, and then create the Students.

Comment: so after create teacher then we get teacher id ? and then make db.Update(&{student{teacher: teacher.id }}) something like that ??

Comment: After Create() the teacher you will have teacher_id. Then you need to Create() Students with this teacher_id.

Comment: it something like we create teacher first then create student again , hmm is there any way to make those automatic to create only once ??

Comment: Why `again`? You create a teacher, next create student. That's all.